# Cannot launch labelme from Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I installed the program "labelme" via Anaconda using the commands from the labelme github

```
    # python3
    conda create --name=labelme python=3.6
    source activate labelme
    # conda install -c conda-forge pyside2
    # conda install pyqt
    pip install pyqt5  # pyqt5 can be installed via pip on python3
    pip install labelme
```

Then, as I was told by another user, I closed the window, reopened and ran the following command:

```
    conda activate labelme
```

Then, as I was also told, I typed "labelme" and ran that as a command. I got the following error:

```
    'labelme' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried reinstalling labelme after updating anaconda and pip. I have searched other methods of opening labelme, but I couldn't find anything.

Labelme is supposed to open as a separate GUI window

Answer (score 0):

After installing labelme as you have done following its documentation, just type these commands in the Anaconda Prompt and it will open the labelme GUI:

```
activate labelme
labelme
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with you.
Probably, labelme was not installed yet.
After typing the codes
`conda create --name=labelme python=3.6`
`conda activate labelme`,
you have to type the code
`pip install labelme`

Then, the install of labelme will start.